# ¿Cómo correr procesos en segundo plano en Django?

Tags: python, django, hilos

En un proyecto terminado y subido a un hosting (namecheap.com), este cuando un usuario quiere puede encender un bot que corra en segundo plano durante todo el día pero me he dado cuenta de que se termina parando y revisando los logos me he encontrado con esto

```
[UID:3232][2752928] Killing runaway process PID: 2762287 with SIGTERM
[UID:3232][2752928] Child process with pid: 2762287 was killed by signal: 15, core dump: 0
```

¿Cómo puedo correr un proceso en segundo plano y que no se detenga?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes lanzar directamente tareas en segundo plano que tarden más que el tiempo límite de ejecución del servidor (unos minutos como mucho).

Tendrías que usar algo parecido a esto: https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Con esta librería es posible correr la web y al mismo tiempo ejecutar tareas en segundo plano al mismo tiempo? Mi idea es que esta función esté ejecutándose durante las 24 horas

Comment: Yo personalmente no lo he usado, preo que podría servirte. Tendrías que poder crear tareas de cron en tu hosting. Defines las tareas con la librería y luego ejecutas `python manage.py process_tasks` desde cron de vez en cuando para que revise las pendientes y las ejecute.